# Method for LaTeX to ignore special characters in a phrase

Tags: urls, characters

Is there an easy way for Latex to ignore all special characters in a given phrase? For example, I had to copy several links which contained the symbol _ . I know that it is possible to put `\` in front of every special character, to ignore it. But I was wondering if there is a command of the form

`\ignore{^&%$###___}` that outputs exactly '`^&%$###___`'  in the pdf document?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To just insert the characters, use `\verb|^&%$###___|`. But this doesn't insert any line breaks.

To give the string proper line breaks for a url, `\usepackage{url}` and use `\url{^&%$###___}`.

To also make it a clickable link, `\usepackage{hyperref}` and again use `\url{^&%$###___}`.

Comment: if one do not need the features of `hyperref` it makes more sense to use `\usepackage{url}`

Comment: So I guess the answer to the OP question is "no" (this isn't clearly stated in this answer).

Comment: How do you include the | symbol inside verb though?